# The Imitation Game - 10 men checking one setting a minute

Tags: the-imitation-game

In the movie when Cumberbatch said the following phrase

> There are 159 million, million, million possible Enigma settings. All
>   we had to do was try each one. But if we had 10 men checking one
>   setting a minute for 24 hours every day and seven days every week

the sentence

> 10 men checking one setting a minute

does it mean 10 men checking on single setting in one single minute, or that each of the 10 men is checking a setting in a minute, which will make 10 settings for one minute?

Answer (score 2):

His meaning is this, that there would be 10 men each checking their own unique setting in a minute. It's just said to further demonstrate the grand scale/how near impossible it was to crack the enigma.